# Simple select from JSON

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, ssjs

I'm sure this is a dumb question, I just can't get it to work and I can't figure out why.

I have this JSON:

```
[{"prop1":"250","prop2":"1"},{"prop1":"500","prop2":"2"},{"prop1":"750","prop2":"3"}]
```

I'm trying to target a specific property value, in this case I want to return the value "250", but I don't seem to succeed.
I'm testing it on a cloudpage.

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
  
  var response = HTTP.Get("MyUrlToTheJson");
  var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.content);
  Write(obj[0].prop1);
</script>
```

But it never returns any value.
How do I return the value "250" from my JSON?

Comment: You probably need to print the result to see whether you parsed the JSON successfully. Try to print the obj variable first

Comment: I did that before I tested this.
But your comment made me do it again, and this time I realized my error.

I keep forgetting the importance of capitalization.

I simply needed a capital "C" in Content. 
var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Content);

Comment: Great. So the issue is solved now?

Comment: Yes, will post answer

Answer (score 1):

I simply needed a capital "C" in Content.
Thanks for making me realize, Duc Le.

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
  
  var response = HTTP.Get("MyUrlToTheJson");
  var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Content);
  Write(obj[0].prop1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I approach finding JSON paths in the context of SFMC with SSJS:

```javascript
<script language="javascript" runat="server">

  Platform.Load("Core","1");
  
  var response = HTTP.Get("https://httpbin.org/json");
  var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Content);
  Write(Stringify(obj));
  
  // paste results into jsonpathfinder.com
  // click Beautify
  // select the desired path, and note the path returned
  
  Write("<br>author:" + obj.slideshow.author);

</script>
```

Try it yourself: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/APBrmuSk